# How to read values from collections returned by Google splitter?

Tags: string, hashmap, guava, splitter

```
    MvcResult result;
    result = this.mockMvc.perform(something).andExpect( status().isOk() ).andReturn();

    String resultAsString = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

/* resultAsString = "{"abc":"def","ghi":"jkl","mno":"pqr"}" */

    String resultAsString1 = StringUtils.remove( resultAsString, "{" );
            resultAsString1 = StringUtils.remove( resultAsString1, "}" );

    Map<String, String> resultAsMap = Splitter.on( "," ).withKeyValueSeparator( ":" ).split( resultAsString1 );

    String myValueName = (String) resultAsMap.get( "mno" );
```

But in debug mode, what I'm seeing is that myValueName = null.

Can someone please help?

I'm importing com.google.common.base.Splitter;

Comment: Try printing `resultAsMap.keySet()` - you'll likely see that your keys are quoted (e.g. `"mno"`). You could do `resultAsMap.get("\"mno\"")`, but using a proper JSON library like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) will be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys in the input string are enclosed in quotes, but the key used for the map lookup isn't. You may want to use a JSON library instead, like Gson:

```
JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) (new JsonParser().parse("{\"key\": \"value\"}"));
String value = obj.get("key");
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the usage of the JSON library, you are talking about ?... Anyway thanks, it worked.

Comment: That is [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), a library for deserializing JSON strings, like the one in your question, into Java objects.